# ¿Cómo pausar un script de Python por unos segundos?

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un programa para que abra páginas y las cierre después de 30 segundos. Tengo todo hecho, sólo me falta el timer de 30 segundos, que no se cómo introducirlo. ¿Alguien sabe la solución?

Aquí el script:

```
import webbrowser  
import os

def openWindow():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.es')

openWindow()

# Aqui va el timer

browserExe = "chrome.exe"
os.system("taskkill /f /im "+browserExe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza el método [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) dentro del módulo `time`:

```
import time
time.sleep(30)
```

Esto detiene la ejecución del programa durante 30 segundos.